# How can I create a litter square at the right-bottom of a border table cell?

Tags: html, css

How can I add a little square at the bottom right of a table cell?

It just like a selected cell in excel.

[image]

I have tried to add a div in the cell, however, it makes the content does not be placed in the centre of the cell. So, I don't know how to do so.

HTML:

```css
.borderCell
{
 border:1px inset #e0e0e0;
}
.borderCell:after
{ 
 border:2px inset transparent;
}
.dateCell
{
 padding: 0px;
 font-size:17px;
 width:25px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="borderCell alignCenter" contenteditable="true">
      b
      <div style="width:5px;height:5px;background-color:blue;float:right"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you provide your code so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 10px;
}

td.parentsqure {
  position: relative;
}

.squre {
  height: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>test 1</td>
    <td class="parentsqure">
      test 2
      <div class="squre"></div>
    </td>
    <td>test 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to consider an extra element, use a simple background:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 10px;
}

td.parentsqure {
  background: linear-gradient(red,red) bottom right/5px 5px no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>test 1</td>
    <td class="parentsqure">
      test 2
    </td>
    <td>test 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This solution cannot be applied to my situation.

Comment: it's still a valid solution based on your actual question. It can be helpful for someone else